# How Can I Check If String Starts With iFrame?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

We are building a newsfeed app where some of the posts contain iframed youtube videos and others do not. In order for the videos to be responsive, we have wrapped div in a div with a class of "video container". However, we only want that class to be active when the data string starts with .

This is for items in a v-for loop.

Using vuejs, how can we check to see if the data string includes "iframe"?

```
<v-card-text class="pt-1 pb-0">
      <div :class="{'video-container': 
(videoCheck(props.item.content) )}">
   <p v-html="props.item.content"></p>
      </div>
</v-card-text>
```

and the method:

```
videoCheck: function(item){
  var substring = "<iframe>"
  return item.includes(substring)
},
```

Comment: What is the problem you're encountering? It seems like you've worked it out already from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, the most backwards compatible solution is to use [`indexOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp):

`return item.indexOf(substring) == 0;`

There is also [`startsWith`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp) in all latest browsers:

`return item.startsWith(substring);`

Comment: NOTE: i am assuming that `item` is a string

Comment: Just `toString()` then substring it.

Comment: Here's a sample item: <iframe class="ql-video" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EKZw1m0RHAY"></iframe><p><br></p>